# Error with Laravel Routing

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently playing around with Laravel trying to implement a past project with it to see how it works. I've run into a slight error with url resources. According to the Laravel docs you're allowed URLs with multiple variables. Thanks for all the help Laravel Experts!

```
Route::resource('agents/report/{id}', 'ClientController@reportSelection');
Route::resource('agents/report/{id}/{month}/{year}', 'ClientController@report');

LogicException
Route pattern "/agents/reports/{id}/{{id}}" cannot reference variable name "id" more than once.
```

Comment: Sorry, but [what is your question exactly](http://www.whatisyourquestionexactly.com), and what warnings/errors are you receiving?

Comment: why u using `resource` routes here ?

Comment: Show us your traceback.

Answer (score 0):

`Route::resource(..)` creates a [whole bunch of routes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) with a single line of code, which might or might not be what you want.

For your specific usecase, try the following:

**Simple approach**

```
Route::get('agents/report/{id}', 'ClientController@reportSelection');
Route::get('agents/report/{id}/{month}/{year}', 'ClientController@report');
```

Or if you want to stay consistent using **named routes**:

```
Route::get('agents/report/{id}', ['as' => 'agents.reportById', 'uses' => 'ClientController@reportSelection']);
Route::get('agents/report/{id}/{month}/{year}', ['as' => 'agents.reportByIdAndDate', 'uses' => 'ClientController@report']);
```

If you are just starting to learn laravel, I can recommend Jeffrey Ways free Laracasts Series [Laravel 4 from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/) which covers everything you need to get startet and most importantly, to get Laravel right. It is devided into 16 parts, you so can consume just the parts you need. It also contains a screencast on [resourceful routing](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/9), which might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

when using resourcefull routing your syntax should be like this

```
Route::resource('agents/report', 'ClientController');
```

if you want to use functions with controllers you can use the below code

```
Route::ger('agents/report/{id}', 'ClientController@reportSelection');
Route::get('agents/report/{id}/{month}/{year}', 'ClientController@report');
```